# EC2 "clone" from snapshot NOT working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I wanted to take a pre-existing t2.medium EC2 instance and essentially clone it. Knowing no exact feature exists within AWS I scoured their documentation, asked people I know and came up with:

- Create snapshot of said EC2 instance
- Create AMI of snapshot
- Build EC2 instance from AMI

When I went to build the new EC2 I was only given the option for a t1.micro OR m3.medium and above. I tried both (in and out of same region as original) and kept getting "insufficient data" under Status Checks.

Any ideas on what is going on here?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g2j3S2CfTQU

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you selected "paravirtual" as the virtualization type when you created the AMI, when you should have selected "hvm".

If you are doing this from the console you can create an AMI directly from the pre-existing EC2 instance, skipping the manual snapshot step, which should automatically use the correct settings for the AMI.

Comment: Perfect! Any pros/cons using paravirtual vs hvm in general?
Ty!

Comment: Amazon's advice is "For the best performance, we recommend that you use current generation instance types and HVM AMIs when you launch your instances" (at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/virtualization_types.html). More here: http://cloudnative.io/blog/2014/07/paravirtual-vs-hvm-images/